# Is there any way to make a Qt DLL that statically links to the Qt runtimes?

Tags: c++, qt

I have written a DLL in Qt. If I try to statically build it (so that you don't need Qt installed in order to use the DLL), it becomes a .lib file. Is there any way to statically build the DLL file without making it a .lib file?

I have two Qt installations. The non-static one creates a DLL file but the static one creates a LIB file.

Answer (score 1):

You need to make sure that your Qt installation is statically built in order to link statically. I would check the Qt license for linking statically though as you may have to open source your project in order to legally link Qt statically in accordance with LGPL.

Comment: Yes, I have two Qt installations. The non-static one creates a DLL file but the static one creates a LIB file.

Answer (score 0):

You want to build a dynamically linked library with dependencies statically linked.
You library will be compiled to be a DLL, but the Qt dependency needs to be statically linked against your library.

Comment: You will want to have TEMPLATE = LIB in your .pro file, run qmake to generate the projects Makefile and then inspect it and edit it to force it to link Qt statically.